# Errno::ENOENT No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I'm using RoR 2.3.8, I want to read a .csv file with is in "path"

```
def run(filepath, contact_id, filename)
        path = "#{filepath}/#{filename}"
        Rails.logger.info path
        return ["The file "+ filename +" does not exist"] unless File.exist?(path)

        CSV.foreach(File.basename(path), {:col_sep => @seperator}) do |row|
```

When I do that I get this error:

```
Errno::ENOENT in Admin::RoutesController#status_race

No such file or directory - /Users/anna/Documents/aphroditel/route_finder/arbinet/app/importersQuickcom-Standard-20121107-FULL.csv`
```

But I'm completely sure that the path is right and the file is there. What I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like that path is wrong anyway, could you give the line where you define `path` variable ? Or debug the path value before the line you gave ?

Comment: Please udpate your answer instead of adding this in your comment, will be more readable. Also I can not see the logger output. I'm wondering in the log you gave why there is a trailing `\`` but it may just be added by the exception reporter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try without the `File.basename`?

```
CSV.foreach(path, {:col_sep => @seperator}) do |row|
```